# Data from Blade File not rendering in Vue Component

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I am working in Laravel Blade and trying to convert some blade files to vue components. I have a property in my blade file of pagetitle. I am trying to get the dynamically created page title to render on the screen from my vue component and not blade. But in my vue console, data comes back as "". Not sure why the data is carrying over.

Header.vue

```
    <template>
        <div>
            <p title="page-title">{{pageTitle}}</p>
        </div>

    </template>



   <script>
     export default {
     props: {
        pageTitle: {
            type: String
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
```

app.js

```
    window.Vue = require('vue');

    import Header from './components/Header';
    Vue.component('header', Header);

    const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
    });
```

main.blade.php

```
<div id="app">
    <header :page-title="{{$pageTitle}}"></header>
</div>
```

header.blade.php //where page title is being pulled from

```
    <title>
        {{ $pageTitle ?? 'Default Page Title' }}
    </title>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Header.vue file you are defining `pageTitle` as a data property, while it should be defined as a `prop`, since you are actually providing it as a property on the `header` component.

```js
props: {
    pageTitle: {
        type: String
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, try it. See second answer for link to component props

Answer (score 1):

There already exists an HTML element called [header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header), I suggest you rename your component. Your component is missing a `props` attribute to take input from blade:

Pagetitle.vue:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p title="page-title">{{ this.pageTitle}}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['title'],
        data() {
            return {
                pageTitle: '',
            };
        },
        created() {
            this.pageTitle = this.title
        }
    }
</script>
```

We created a `title` property. When the component is created, we set the component's `pageTitle` to the `title` given in `main.blade.php`.

app.js

```
window.Vue = require('vue');

import Pagetitle from './components/Pagetitle';
Vue.component('pagetitle', Pagetitle);

const app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
});
```

main.blade.php

```
<div id="app">
    <pagetitle :title="foo bar"></pagetitle>
</div>
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

Comment: So I changed my componenet name. page title is supposed to be a <title> tag but Vue does not allow that, how do I get my pageTitle to show up as a title in the browsers tab like a typical title?

Comment: Vue only renders inside your `<div id="app">...</div>`, that's not where your `<head>` or `<title>` are. Do you really need a Vue component for "a simple" `<title>` element? Sounds like overkill

Comment: I am just setting the flow for how all other components willl generally be made. The main concern here is that in the VUE debugging tools My title is still returning as blank -> (title: " "); I care more about the data passing through